# Not installed package shows file conflict

Tags: rpm

I'm facing facing conflict issue while installing a RPM that is not already installed. I tried 'yum clean all' but it didn't change anything. Is the issue related to the package and not OS.

RHEL 7.7 x86_64

```
 [root@server dumps]# rpm -ivh pdksh-5.2.14-30.x86_64.rpm
warning: pdksh-5.2.14-30.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 4f2a6fd2: NOKEY
Preparing...                          ################################# [100%]
        file /usr/bin/ksh conflicts between attempted installs of pdksh-5.2.14-30.x86_64 and pdksh-5.2.14-30.x86_64
[root@server dumps]#
[root@server dumps]# ll /usr/bin/ksh
ls: cannot access /usr/bin/ksh: No such file or directory
[root@server dumps]#
[root@server dumps]# rpm -qa | grep -i ksh
[root@server dumps]#
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not say where the package came from, but if that is the same version [from Fedora Linux Core 3](https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/core/3/x86_64/os/Fedora/RPMS/pdksh-5.2.14-30.x86_64.rpm) then I see what the problem is.

The problem is that the `pdksh-5.2.14-30.x86_64.rpm` package is conflicting with itself.  That is why the name is listed in the error twice.

If you look at `rpm -qlp pdksh-5.2.14-30.x86_64.rpm`, you would see a number of entries, but the conflicts are `/bin/ksh` and `/usr/bin/ksh`.  Those used to be different locations in Fedora and they supplied two different files in the package.  In your RHEL 7 system, the location `/bin` and `/usr/bin` are the same location, and an RPM cannot install two different files to the same location.

It appears that RedHat no longer packages `pdksh` and instead delivers `mksh` and `ksh`.  If you cannot use one of those, I would suggest rebuilding the [source package](https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/core/3/SRPMS/pdksh-5.2.14-30.src.rpm) without installing files to `/bin` or just compiling the software from source.

Comment: I'm not aware from where the package was downloaded, someone else did but I can see it is available through https://access.redhat.com/downloads/content/package-browser

Comment: The location of where the package was downloaded from would only be necessary if the contents differ from what I have described in my answer.  Did you look at the output of `rpm -qlp $YOUR_RPM_FILE`?  Does it have have the same files in both `/bin` and `/usr/bin`?  If so, that is the source of your conflict.  The solution would be to not use that package originally published in 2004, and instead find something built to be used with RHEL 7.